# Failed to pull image on EKS created by Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I created EKS using Terraform, then I am trying to install aws-load-balancer using helm
it gives me this error

> "Failed to pull image "602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon/aws-load-balancer-controller:v2.4.5": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head "https://602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/amazon/aws-load-balancer-controller/manifests/v2.4.5": no basic auth credentials"

why there is no basic auth credentials ?
How to make it pull the image from another region? my EKS is in Asia not us-west-2 ?

Note:
EKS is in a private subnet, I am using AWS CodeBuild to run Terraform and deploy EKS, in the last step of CodeBuild I run a simple HELM command to deploy

```
 # Install AWS LoadBalancer Controller
resource "helm_release" "aws-lb-controller" {
  name       = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  chart      = "eks/aws-load-balancer-controller"
  repository =  "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts"

  values = []

  set {
    name  = "region"
    value = "ap-southeast-1"
  }
  set {
    name  = "image.repository"
    value = "public.ecr.aws/eks/aws-load-balancer-controller"
  }
  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = "v2.4.5"
  }
  set {
    name  = "namespace"
    value = "kube-system"
  }
  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.create"
    value = "false"
  }
  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.name"
    value = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  }
  set {
    name  = "ingress-class"
    value = "alb"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.admissionWebhooks.enabled"
    value = "false"
  }
}
```

Why EKS failed to pull the image ?

Comment: Can you add the terraform code you have to the question?

Comment: hope you deployment have the imagepullsecret.

Comment: Added the Terraform code, thank you in advance!